# Space with Hiragana Input

Tags: keybindings, input-source, japanese

For whatever reason Memrise requires you to input a space character in some Japanese answers (I'm very much a beginner, so this may not be as weird as I think). However when I have my input set to `Hiragana` with `Romaji` typing method, pressing <kbd>space</kbd> converts what I've already typed into Kanji even though I have `Live Conversion` disabled (I think that's what it's doing, they're not Kanji I recognize but I don't know what else they might be). Obviously this is very annoying as I keep getting answers wrong when all I'm missing is a space or I'll have random Kanji in the middle of what I'm typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that holding <kbd>shift</kbd> while pressing <kbd>space</kbd> will input a normal space character if you have the `Shift key action` set to `Enter Romaji mode`.